# Teradata - joining char with varchar

Tags: sql, join, teradata, sqldatatypes

I have two tables A and B. And I want to join A with B on A.col_1 = B.col_2. col_1 has datatype VARCHAR(35) while col_2 has datatype CHAR(35). The following statement caused problem while joining the two tables: no record returned, which mean the two tables cannot be joined. col_1 usually has 8 - 11 digits, the same with col_2. My understanding is the even I used "LENGTH(B.col_2 )-1" but the trailing spaces should not be problems as long as the values of col_1 and col_2 are the same.

What is causing this issue?

```
ON A.col_1 =SUBSTR(B.col_2 ,1,LENGTH(B.col_2 )-1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does Teradata not have a trim function?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes Teradata does have trim and that was my original solution, which worked. But my question was since the trailing spaces does not matter when joining when why trim the trailing the spaces was the solution? I made the change but when I look back I am curious.

Comment: I'm nowhere near at the bottom of this, but I have found situation in Teradata where `A = B` is resulting in false when A & B are the same excepting trailing spaces...  I may raise a questionfor this one day.  I've been totally _unable_ to create a simple minimal reproducable scenario :-(  Maybe linked to tmode=ANSI/TERA too ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess B is the char.
This will explain you what happens here:

```
select char_length(cast('abc' as char(10)));
```

> 10

Your substr does not take the real length of the char string but the padded length, therefore you get the original string minus 1 space.

In order to solve the issue use -

```
SUBSTR(B.col_2 ,1,LENGTH(cast(B.col_2 as varchar(35))-1)
```

or

```
SUBSTR(B.col_2 ,1,LENGTH(rtrim(B.col_2)-1)
```

---

... and yes, char/varchar does not matter for comparison

```
select 1 where cast('abc' as varchar(10)) = cast('abc' as char(10))
```

> 1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I really appreciate it. So I did the char2hexint checks, and for example for one record I have "3535363130393031                                                      " for col_1 and "35353631303930313520202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020  " for column two. What does this mean? Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look?

Comment: Hi Dudu, I had the same solution as you suggested. But my question is: since the trailing spaces should not matter when joining a char and varchar as long as the value are equal. So even the lengths are not equal they should be able to join with each other. Is there other reasons that may cause this problem?

Comment: I explained it in my answer. suppose you have `'ABC'` (varchar) and `'ABC     '` (char). You are not trying to compare then "as is" - you want to ignore the last character. The problem is what you are actually doing ,is taking `'AB'` from the 1st but `'ABC    '` (1 less space) from the 2nd. The reason is that char_length on char(35) will always return 35.